# When a user selects certain inputs in an Input Fields, and clicks "Search" it console.logs("hello")

Tags: javascript, html, input, dropdown

As the title suggests, when a user selects the letter 'B' in all the input fields, and clicks search it then will console.log('hello')

No eventually I want it to take them to anotehr page but I feel like that will come easy after I have this part down.

Help Me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're My Only Hope.

Here is what I have so far

HTML

```
<select id='inputOne'> 
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="">A</option>
    <option value="">B</option>
    <option value="">C</option>
</select>

<select id='inputTwo'>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="">A</option>
    <option value="">B</option>
    <option value="">C</option>
</select>

<select id='inputThree'>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="">A</option>
    <option value="">B</option>
    <option value="">C</option>
</select>

<button type='button' onclick='myFunction()'>search</button>
```

JavaScript

```
//Assigned Variable to html elements

const inputOne = document.getElementById('inputOne');
const inputTwo = document.getElementById('inputTwo');
const inputThree = document.getElementById('inputThree');      


//function to open a new page(or in this case say hekllo in the console)      

function myFunction() {
  
  if(inputOne == 'B' && inputTwo == 'B' &&  inputThree == 'B') {
    console.log('hello')
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Check out [how to get the currently selected value of an select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) and [how to trigger a function when the selected value is changed](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp).

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply! The value link you provided was super helpful, but i dont believe the onchange can be used in this situation since the key event im utilizing is onclick. Is the there another solution that may be more beneficial? Thank you

Comment: My bad, I didn't see you were using a button to search. Your current way should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code:

1. Assigned value for each option
2. reading value of the selected item as input.value

```js
//Assigned Variable to html elements

const inputOne = document.getElementById('inputOne');
const inputTwo = document.getElementById('inputTwo');
const inputThree = document.getElementById('inputThree');      


//function to open a new page(or in this case say hekllo in the console)      

function myFunction() {
  if(inputOne.value == 'B' && inputTwo.value == 'B' &&  inputThree.value == 'B') {
    console.log('hello')
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
  
}
```

```html
<select id='inputOne'> 
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select id='inputTwo'>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select id='inputThree'>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<button type='button' onclick='myFunction()'>search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You beat me by a min or two. My solution (very similar):

```
<select id='inputOne'>
    <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<select id='inputTwo'>
    <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<select id='inputThree'>
    <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<button type='button' id="searchButton">search</button>


<script>

    //Assigned Variable to html elements

    const inputOne = document.getElementById('inputOne');
    const inputTwo = document.getElementById('inputTwo');
    const inputThree = document.getElementById('inputThree');
    const searchButton = document.getElementById('searchButton');




    searchButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var a = inputOne.value;
        var b = inputTwo.value;
        var c = inputThree.value
        if (a === 'b' && b === 'b' && c === 'b') {
            console.log('Hello');
        }


    });



</script>
```

Comment: OH MY GOSH I LOVE THIS. Reassigning the value makes the if stamtments so much shorter. Youre such a homie! Will use. Thank you!!